# This job depends on other jobs with expired / erased artifact

Tags: python-requests, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, cicd

I have a python project which uses Gitlab Job retry api to retry a job of a pipeline.
But my retry job is getting failed with the error "This job depends on other jobs with expired / erased artifact". What could be the reason for this error?

```
stages:

- build


build:

tags: [kubernetes, linux, default]

image: #image-url

stage: build

script:

- python3 setup.py sdist bdist wheel

artifacts:

paths:

- $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist

- ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/job

- ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/*.egg-info/PKG-INFO

expire_in: 600 mins
```

Comment: Could u share your .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: @Origin have shared the yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your artifacts expire after 600 minutes, so if you re-run a pipeline stage later than that, the artifact will not be present any more. If the pipeline stage you re-ran depends on a previous stage's artifact, then the error you are seeing occurs